# Disable Reactions in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
   if payload.emoji.name == '❌':
      #code
   elif payload.emoji.name == '✅':
      #code
```

When someone reacts with an x it runs the code but when he reacts with a tick after reacting with the x it also runs the code under the tick is there a way of disabling reactions after someone has already reacted?

Answer (score 1):

Store the payload.user_id in a data structure, add the user_id to the structure and make sure to check if the payload.user_id is not in the structure before running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did that:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    # Checks reactions only in the logchannel
    if reaction.message.channel.id != logchannel.id:
        return

    total_reactions = 0

    for r in reaction.message.reactions:
        total_reactions += r.count

    member = reaction.message.mentions[0]
    if total_reactions == 3:
        if reaction.emoji == "✅":
            # Stuff
        elif reaction.emoji == "❌":
            # Stuff
    elif total_reactions > 3:
        await reaction.remove(user)
```

My goal with this code is to make it so that there are 2 bot reactions and 1 user reaction at all times.

I first count the total reactions on the message by iterating through the message's reactions.
Then, if there are more than 3 reactions (meaning the user has reacted more than once), I don't execute any of the code and instead immediately remove that user's reaction.

This makes it so that after you react to 1 emoji, it's impossible to react to the other, and no other user can react as well.

Hope this helps!